# Extending convergence of a Sequence of Integrals on any Interval in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to all of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let the non-negative real valued functions $f, f_1, f_2, ...\in L^1[\mathbb{R}^n]$ be bounded and continuous a.e. on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\lambda_n$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\lim_{m\to\infty} f_m(x)=f(x)$. Suppose that
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\int_{R}f_m d\lambda_n=\int_{R}f d\lambda_n$$ for *any* rectangle $R\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ with sides parallel to the coordinate axes.

Are these conditions sufficient to conclude that

$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f_m d\lambda_n=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f d\lambda_n  ?\hspace{.5in} (1) $$

If so, how can this convergence in (1) be proved? If not, what additional condition(s), if any, other than that the sequence $\{f_m\}$ be increasing or dominated by a real valued function in $L^1[\mathbb{R}^n]$ could be imposed to conclude that the convergence of integrals in (1) holds ?

Comment: You're using $n$ for different things: indexing $f_n$ and the limit, $\Bbb R^{n}$, $\lambda_n$. Is $\lambda_n$ supposed to be the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R^{n}$?

Comment: Thank you for informing me of this typo. I fixed the question so that the index of the sequence now differs from the dimension of the integral and the Lebesgue measure $\lambda_n$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

A simple counter-example is $ n=1,f_m=\frac 1 m \chi_{(m,2m)}, f=0$.